# ReactJS.net - How do I use ES6 modules

Tags: reactjs.net

I have ReactJS.Net successfully running, including using ES6 syntax.

I am using the default Jsx transformation pipeline, which is using Babel.
Looking at source in the browser I can see that ES6 code has been converted to ES5 by ReactJS.Net

I have been unable to get modules working.

The browser gives me 2 errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

How do I use ES6 Modules?

Simplest example:

Lib.js

```
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

UserOfLib.js

```
import { square } from 'Lib';
console.log(square(11));
```

Gets transformed to this (looking at browser source):

Lib:

```
// @hash v3-AD133907ABEC5D32B3768A3AF2301FC9
// Automatically generated by ReactJS.NET. Do not edit, your changes will be overridden.
// Version: 2.0.1 (build 5e9476a)
// Generated at: 08-Nov-15 6:40:26 AM
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.square = square;

function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

UserOfLib:

```
// @hash v3-812C209AFED25C2B4507E5769B0D899B
// Automatically generated by ReactJS.NET. Do not edit, your changes will be overridden.
// Version: 2.0.1 (build 5e9476a)
// Generated at: 08-Nov-15 6:40:26 AM
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var _Lib = require('Lib');

console.log((0, _Lib.square)(11)); // 121
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently, ReactJS.Net does not handle modules. If you want to use modules, you'll need to use a module bundler such as Webpack or Browserify to compile the modules down to vanilla JavaScript. Implementing support for modules in ReactJS.NET itself is a non-trivial amount of work, since it'd need to deal with dependencies and loading modules in the correct order, and good well-tested solutions like Webpack already exist.

Comment: Could these two be used in combination with JSX processing?